# jTable not visable in panel i have created

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable

I have created my own version of a panel so I can create some dragable tables but at the moment nothing is being added on to the panel I have created

panel class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Workspace extends JPanel implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{
    private JTable t;
    private DatabaseHandler d;
    public Workspace(DatabaseHandler d ){
        super();
        this.d = d;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
        this.setLayout(null);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void load(String table){
        t = new JTable(d.getTable(table));
        //JScrollPane js=new JScrollPane(t);
        this.add(t);
    }
}
```

the code which calls it:

```
public class Display{
   private JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
   public JList list;
   public JFrame frame;
   private DatabaseHandler d = new DatabaseHandler("imdb");
   private Workspace w = new Workspace(d);

   public Display(){

       //create the window
       frame = new JFrame("FYP - Database Refactoring");
       frame.getContentPane().add(w, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       frame.setSize(1000,1000);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       list = new JList(d.getTableNames());
       list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
           public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
               JList l = (JList)e.getSource();
               w.load((String)l.getSelectedValue());
               frame.setVisible(true);
           }
       });
       leftPanel.add(list);
       JLabel l = new JLabel("workbench");
      w.add(l);
       frame.getContentPane().add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Display();
   }
}
```

Any help would be appricated

Comment: Using a null layout is a bad idea. You should use [a real layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: i know, i will add a layout at the moment i am just testing at the moment

Comment: And in fact the null layout is messing you up. @resueman: you should make that an answer. @ slightly clueless, then that's a **bad** test and again is totally messing you up. Your JTable should also be held in a JScrollPane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Avoid null layouts, and in fact this one is messing you up, since with null layouts, you must fully specify call component sizes and locations. Just don't do it.
2. Don't re-add JTables in the MouseListener. Rather give your JPanel a JTable, and change its model from the MouseListener. Otherwise you're adding multiple JTables which doesn't make sense.
3. Put your JTable into a JScrollPane
4. And best to have your JPanel use BorderLayout and put the JScrollPane into the BorderLayout.CENTER position.

Answer (score 3):

> so I can create some dragable tables

If you need the ability to drag a JTable I would suggest that you should be using a `JDesktopPane` with `JInternalFrames`. You can easily drag an internal frame around the desktop. Then you just add the `JTable\JScrollPane` to the internal frame like you would to a normal JFrame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Internal Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for more information and working examples.